# how to count word numbers in python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I'm Having a csv files with 2 columns named Words and Frequency and want to return the sum of number of words with frequency of 2 and less this is the code I'm trying to use but it says

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

```py
df=pd.read_csv('dictionary.csv')

result=(sum(df['word'] if df['freq']<=2))
print("the number of words appearing  less than 3 times are :{}".format{reslt})
```

data sample

[image]

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If want count number of rows matching condition, so it means number of `True`s of mask only use `sum`:

```
result = (df['freq']<=2).sum()
```

Or:

```
result = df['freq'].le(2).sum()
```

Comment: Won't he get the same issue? Column `word` not being able to be summed? Well I am assuming `word` is column that contains lists containing words

Comment: I'm getting the column values in stead of the sum of  the column numbers

Comment: the number of words appearing  less than 3 times are :youAlexHithankisInamefineamhowaremy

Comment: which suppose to be **the number of words appearing  less than 3 times are : 12**

Comment: @programmingfreak - hmmm, is possible add some data sample? Because not easy answer with no data

Comment: Please update your question with some print of your data so we can help you address the issue!

Comment: sure word,freq
done,5
fly,4
Hi,2
Alex,2
you,2
my,1
I,1
fine,1
are,1
is,1
thank,1
am,1
how,1
name,1

Comment: @JimEisenberg - simpliest is `sum`

Comment: as usual works perfectly thank you man, I will vote up the answer in 11 hours coz my votes are done for today :D

Comment: Go Jez, we partying at 500k! Is there any performance difference between filtering with `eq()`,`le()`, etc... instead of the operator `==`,`>=`?

Comment: @CeliusStingher - i t is more general, because possible add `axis` parameter for `DataFrame.some_func` and mainly it is less `()`, so in my opinion more clean code.